# Ubuntu 20.04 screen flickering during boot

Tags: boot, drivers, flicker

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04. On the second day my screen started to flicker (display random white screens) during shut down/boot.

The next day, when I tried to boot, the problem was still present. Assuming it to be a hardware problem I opened up my LCD panel and cleaned up a bit which somehow fixed it.

It did not had any issue as long as used the sleep mode until I tried to shut it down. At the end of the shutdown process the screen started flickering again. I tried to boot up the system right away but it was still flickering.

I am new to Linux so I don't have any idea what is going on. Please provide with a detailed answer.

I assume it to be a software issue because the flickering occurs only on certain moments.

I use 4 yrs old Lenovo G50-80,Intel core i3, on Intel graphics.

Comment: The certain moments when it happens is during booting up the system or shutting it down. Other than that this problem does not show any where not even when the system is locked (sleep mode). While booting up the system the screen flickers i dont know how long but i try to foce shut it down and try to reboot after 3-4 attempts it some how goes to a black screen where it shows option to enter the safe mode or normally boot the system after booting up normally it works just fine. This thing started yesterday and all of the above things happened tday but when i shut it dwn at night it startd again

Comment: For that screen thing i just took off the safety panel, unscrewed the lcd detatched the cable connecting to the board cleaned it up a bit and placed it back but even after that the problem was still there but when i tried to boot it again then it was normal. I thought it may be some glitch so i updated the system and the assumed its fine now but at the end of the day when i shut down the system everything was fine until the last point and it started again. I tried to boot it again and it was still there. I am unable to access my pc.